# How to minimize a winforms app when there is at least one modal window opened

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two form classes (Form1 and Form2) in a Winforms App.

Form1 is like this:

[image: Form1 with a button on it]

Form2 is like this (ShowInTaskbar = false):

[image: Form2 with an OK and Cancel buttons]

And this code on Form1:

```
    Form2 someForm = new Form2();
    private void btOpenAnotherWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (someForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            MessageBox.Show("OK!!!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Not OK.");
    }
```

That is, a window with a button which opens **modally** another windows when clicked, and waits for the user to close the second window (by clicking the "OK" or "Cancel" button). And depending how it was closed, do alternating actions (represented here by the MessageBox.Show() calls).

I need:

1. The user can use only one window at a time. (Modal forms, That's why I used ShowDialog() instead of Show())
2. When the form closes, do something depending on how the form was closed (the "if (someForm.ShowDialog(this)...")
3. To be able (as a user) to minimize the WHOLE APP.
4. To be able to "unminimize" the app to the former state correctly.
5. The program to respond to WIN+M (minimize all) keys combination.

the above example fails in two ways:

1. (need 5) Doesn't respond to WIN+M
2. (need 3) The app seems to minimize when the Minimize title bar button is clicked, but it is an illusion because the main form (Form1) does not minimize and it is in fact just hidden behind the other opened windows. Only running the example with an empty desktop shows what really happens. Pics follow:

Before Minimize button is clicked:

[image: Empty desktop with the app running]

After:
[image: Empty desktop with the Form2 (someForm) minimized]

Note:

1. The Main form is not minimized
2. The Form2 is in the left botton corner of the screen.

Form2 is a full blown window (not a dialog window per se) and I need the user to interact with it only until it is closed and I also need the user to be able to miminize the whole app in case he needs it.

It is a shame I can't post here the real forms, It would be clearer than these mock-ups.

I need a solution that works with many levels of modal windows (not only two as this example shows). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I may need a little more information about what you're trying to do here.  I have a simple form (Form1) with a button on it, which calls this code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Form1 form2 = new Form1();
     form2.ShowDialog();
  }
```

When I click the button, I get a second instance of the same form, but it's modal.  I still have the option to minimize this second modal form (I obviously can't interact with the first form), and when I do minimize the second form it does minimize the entire application (both forms).  Now obviously you're asking the question, so I don't think I'm understanding you.  =)  What about this scenario do you wish to change?

- C

Comment: When I minimize the second (modal) window, the app´s main form remains freezed and there is no way to minimize it thus there is no way to access the desktop. What the user needs is a way to minimize the app´s main form even though there is modal windows open whithin it, so that she could be temporarily doing some other stuff in other applications or even interacting with the desktop.

Comment: Yanko -  I am unable to repeat your problem.  =(  What operating system are you using?  What version of the .NET Framework are you running?

Comment: Hello. My developing enviroment is running on a Windows XP Pro SP3 with the .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and VS .NET 2008. I have also tested the application in a Windows Vista system with the same result. By the way, thank you and every one that has taken the time to answer to my post.

Comment: Yanko - No problem, sorry you haven't got past this hump yet!  Can you try creating a new project in VS2008 and use the code I posted above?  Just put a button on the default form and put the code in the click event.  I have tried this in VS2010 and VS2008 without issue.  I am running Windows 7 though...

Comment: It happens in XP, Vista and 7. Note that when there are many opened windows it SEEMS the app is minimized, but it really isn't. Only when you try to see the desktop you will see the problem. I posted some pics showing the problem

Comment: I've noticed that in debug mode running under visual studio, when you minimize the modal form, it also minimizes the main form in the application.  When I compile it and install on another machine, I minimize the modal window, but the main window remains frozen.  Scratch that -- the main form is frozen in both cases.  I thought it used to minimize the whole form, though -- will look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some way to hack this functionality using API calls, but I would probably suggest doing some type of overlay with a control inside your main form rather than an actual window. This would allow you to make it "modal" and still have the ability to minimize/resize the main window.

Comment: I can disable the whole window (this.enable = false), and use Show instead of ShowDialog, but that doesn't do anything to the "minimize all opened windows" problem.